# Flexbox not functioning in Android (Samsung) browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Checked answers to similar questions but no help.

I have set up a HTML unordered list, containing 8 items, styled to display horizontally in desktop/laptop. In mobile devices I want the list to resolve to 2 columns/4 rows or 3 columns/3 rows.

Using CSS Flexbox, I've got this happening and, if I work on my laptop and emulate mobile device display in Developer Tools it's fine.

However, if I actually view the page in a mobile device (I'm using a Samsung - so an Android browser) the responsive flex CSS doesn't work (actually, in Android, the horizontal list displays vertically in a single column - which is OK but not what I want).

I have subsequently read that there may be issues with CSS Flexbox in Android.

I'm wondering if there are any ways I might get Flexbox CSS to work in an Android browser? Or have I done something wrong in my code?

MY CSS:

```
ul#flexible {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul#flexible li {
    min-width: 6em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:15px !important;
    flex: 1 0;
}
```

MY HTML:

```
<ul id="flexible">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
ul#flexible {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul#flexible li {
    min-width: 6em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:15px !important;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 0;
            flex: 1 0;
}
```